# Creating a GUI Listbox in matlab to load saved figures

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

I want to add a Listbox to my exsisting Matlab code. I want this listbox on the second tab of my code where the graph is plotted. I want the listbox to be populated with .bmp saved plots in the current folder. I have little experience with MATLAB gui and I am having trouble even displaying the list box.

Here is my current code

```
 function PizanoGUI()
x=linspace(-2,2,100);
power=1;
y=x.^power;
ctrl_fh = figure; 

hPwr = uicontrol('Style','edit','Parent',... 
                     ctrl_fh,...
                     'Position',[45 100 100 20],...
                     'String',num2str(power),...
                     'CallBack',@pwrHandler);

hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','Parent',ctrl_fh,...  
                    'Position',[45 150 100 20],...
                    'String','Reset','Callback',@reset); 

hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','Parent',ctrl_fh,...  
                    'Position',[45 50 100 20],...
                    'String','EXIT','Callback',@close_Callback);                 

htext=uicontrol('Style', 'text',... 
'String', 'Welcome! Please Enter any value p to view the graph of y=x^p then press enter', ... 
'Position',[35,250,500,90], ... 
'FontSize',20);

function close_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

close all;
end

function reset(source,event,handles,varargin) 
    fprintf('resetting...\n');
    power=1;
    set(hPwr,'String',num2str(power));
    y=x.^power;
    close(gcf);
    compute_and_draw_plot();
end

function pwrHandler(source,event,handles,varargin)     
    power=str2num(get(hPwr,'string'));
    fprintf('Setting power to %s\n',get(hPwr,'string'));
    close(gcf);
    compute_and_draw_plot();
end


function compute_and_draw_plot()
    plot_fh = figure;
    y=x.^power;
    figure(plot_fh); plot(x,y)
    xlabel('X axis') 
    ylabel('Y axis') 
    str = sprintf('Plot of Y=X^%d',power);
    title(str);

    hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','Parent',plot_fh,...  
                    'Position',[80 395 100 20],...
                    'String','Previous','Callback',@pushbutton1_Callback);



function pushbutton1_Callback(source, eventdata, handles)
    close(gcf);
    PizanoGUI();
end


 filename = inputdlg('Save figure as...');

 extensions = {'fig','bmp'};

 for k = 1:length(extensions)

saveas(gcf, filename{:}, extensions{k})

set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')

end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Dan, maybe you are looking for something like this then?

Create a folder in the same folder as your script and name it to images, this is where you save your images, then they can easily be loaded again. Create the listbox like this:

```
files = dir('images');
files(strncmp({files.name}, '.', 1)) = [];
nbrOfFiles = length(files(not([files.isdir])));

for i = 1:nbrOfFiles
    listBoxContent{i,1} = files(i).name;
end

handles.listbox1 = uicontrol('Style','listbox','Parent',...                                
                        handles.figure1,...
                        'Position',[100 100 500 50],...
                        'String',listBoxContent,...
                        'CallBack',@loadImage_Callback);
```

And the callback can look something like this:

```
function loadImage_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

 items = get(hObject,'String');
 index_selected = get(hObject,'Value');

 %More code...
```

I don't know what you want to do with the images, but i guess you want to load them somehow. Maybe you know how to do that. Anyway "items(index_selected)" will give you the name of the image selected.

Comment: Thank you for your help Joakim. I used your code to create the listbox. I need the listbox to show the filed in the current matlab folder. After my program is run the user saves the image of the plot to the current matlab folder. I want the listbox to list these saved files. Instead of showing image 1, image 2, image 3 in the listbox I was my saved files to show. I'm not sure if I am being understandable. I am new with Matlab GUI

Comment: I made some changes in my answer, check and see if it's any help.